# dynamic twitter widget id

Tags: twitter

I want to use the new twitter embedded timelines (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) but how can I get the data for the right user by username? I have a lot of websites with users (>500) who have their username in the database but as far as I can see you have to give a data-widget-id to get the tweets from the right user.

Is there any way to do this by username? And if not, how can I quickly convert all my users' data-widget-id to the database?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have the same question. I want to use a PHP variable for the username, I could easily do this with the previous API.

Comment: oh https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18411

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the best you can do is get a single valid `data-widget-id` and use it for many different user names using the `data-screen-name` property.

There is a discussion [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18411) from one of the twitter devs. The same one as @alex_b posted in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrote same script for PHP, for Rails community this gits could be helpfull to get widget-id dynamically.

https://gist.github.com/shah743/dd042df63a8f307f16ed